# Index Match Match return #REF when dragged down

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to fill a table using Index Match Match, which returns me the correct values for the top row, however i get a #Ref! error when I try to drag down the formula vertically. 
I am using this formula:

```
INDEX($C$3:$C$44,MATCH($K$15,$A$3:$A$44,0),MATCH(H16,$B$3:$B$44,0))
```

(See picture for further details on table)
[image]

Any idea where my mistake lies?

Comment: What's the actual contents of the cell: M25?

Comment: When you move to column M, it's still looking at `$K$15` for the Quarter. Perhaps there is no Q2 for that specific row? Maybe try just `=INDEX($C$3:$C$44,MATCH(K$15,$A$3:$A$44,0),MATCH($H16,$B$3:$B$44,0))` (also anchor that `H16` reference to the column)

Comment: the second match is giving how many columns to move over, yet all your years are in a single column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to cell reference locks `$`, and you can place the following formula under Q1 and beside your first row and copy down and to the right.

```
=INDEX($C:$C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$44)/(($A$3:$A$44=H$8)*($B$3:$B$44=$F9)),1))
```

[image: POC]

I believe the problem you are having is that you are trying to return the value in column C that matches a criteria for column A and for column B.  In other words INDEX(Column you want the results from, The row of your result)  Note there is only 1 entry or coma after specifying the the column you will return the results from.  A second column would tell index how many columns to the right to go.

#### PS

AGGREGATE is a special function.  It will perform array like calculations.  Therefore avoid using full column references inside the aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to tweak how it's done, enter this as an Array Formula (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$44,MATCH($K$15&H16,$A$3:$A$44&$B$3:$B$44,0))
```

And drag down.

Edit: Just made a comment, but you might alternatively just need to properly anchor the references:

```
=INDEX($C$3:$C$44,MATCH(K$15,$A$3:$A$44,0),MATCH($H16,$B$3:$B$44,0))
```

Comment: Bruce, in reference to your second formula...INDEX(RANGE,ROWS DOWN, COLUMN ACROSS).  How do you intend to move across columns when you have a 1 dimensional range?  now if you had a two dimensional range I would totally buy what you are saying.

Comment: @ForwardEd - Do you mean with the second formula? I agree actually, after thinking through I think that second "column across" is incorrect. My first reply should work though. (Non-excuse, I haven't had coffee yet :/ )

Comment: yeah I editted my first comment after looking at your first formula and seeing it only had a single match...was not sure how it was going to work, but agreed that it was only going to give 1 number.